# How to use foreach loop inside a Xelement in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

```
 XElement doc = null;
 doc = new XElement("root");
 foreach (var content in emailContents)
                                    {
    doc.Add(new XElement("Email",
            new XElement("FromAddress", content.FromAddress),
            new XElement("EmailReceivedOn", content.receivedOnemail),
            new XElement("Subject", content.subject),
            new XElement("Body", content.body)));
    // I want to add the below code after the body element is created in the xml inside the email element section; How to do the same?
     foreach (var attachment in content.attachments)
        {
          doc.Add(new XElement("attachmentname"), attachment.Filename),
          doc.Add(new XElement(("attachmentpath"), attachment.Filepath)        
        }
}
```

Basically content.attachment is a list of attachment name and i want to add the list just after the body element. How to do the same?

Comment: Just assign `var email = new XElement("Email", ...);` then add it to the `doc`, then add the attachments to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fairly easy to do it in one go:

```
var doc =
    new XElement("root",
        new XElement("Email",
            new XElement("FromAddress", content.FromAddress),
            new XElement("EmailReceivedOn", content.receivedOnemail),
            new XElement("Subject", content.subject),
            new XElement("Body", content.body),
            content.attachments.Select(attachment =>
                new XElement("attachment",
                    new XElement("attachmentname", attachment.Filename),
                    new XElement("attachmentpath", attachment.Filepath)))));
```

I started with this sample data:

```
var content = new
{
    FromAddress = "FromAddress",
    receivedOnemail = "receivedOnemail",
    subject = "subject",
    body = "body",
    attachments = new []
    {
        new
        {
            Filename = "Filename",
            Filepath = "Filepath",
        },
    },
};
```

And I got this XML:

```
<root>
  <Email>
    <FromAddress>FromAddress</FromAddress>
    <EmailReceivedOn>receivedOnemail</EmailReceivedOn>
    <Subject>subject</Subject>
    <Body>body</Body>
    <attachment>
      <attachmentname>Filename</attachmentname>
      <attachmentpath>Filepath</attachmentpath>
    </attachment>
  </Email>
</root>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error --> This method is not supported against a materialized query result.

Comment: @rohitsingh if the list is a query from a database, try using `.ToList()` on it before using `Select()`.

Answer (score 4):

You are adding attachment to root element instead of adding in Email element. you can do it like following.

```
XElement doc = null;
doc = new XElement("root");
doc.Add(new XElement("Email",
        new XElement("FromAddress", content.FromAddress),
        new XElement("EmailReceivedOn", content.receivedOnemail),
        new XElement("Subject", content.subject),
        new XElement("Body", content.body)));
 var email=doc.Element("Email"); // get email element from root Element
 foreach (var attachment in content.attachments)
    {
      //Add attachemnt information to email element.
      email.Add(new XElement("attachmentname"), attachment.Filename),
      email.Add(new XElement(("attachmentpath"), attachment.Filepath)        
    }
```